# Adding style to tooltip title angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to style my tooltip. Now it's coming as a plain windows tooltip. I am using the following code for that:

```
<span  data-tooltip title="{{myText}}" class="has-tip" data-tooltip-position="left">
    {{myText }} 
</span>
```

I am using a dropdown box where I am using `ngrepeat` to populate the content like a table, row by row, so when I tried using the below the pop up is cutdown by the table borders.

```
<span data-tooltip ="{{myText}}" class="has-tip" data-tooltip-position="left">
    {{myText }}
</span>
```

I want to show my tooltip above each row when I hover over the row so that other rows will not be overlapped by the tooltip. I am new to Angular and CSS. Please help.

Comment: check this link: http://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/

Comment: Hi, use [ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip)